# Name of nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with nested arrays, I'm trying to get the name of each item not the value or index.

```
var lcaJan = []; lcaFeb = []; lcaMar = [] ...etc.
var lcaMonth = [lcaJan, lcaFeb, lcaMar, etc...]
```

Then I want to run through each lcaMonth and list the names:

```
$.each( lcaMonth, function (i,v) {
     console.log( //here );
});
```

The //here is where I'm struggling to find. If I do `console.log(lcaMonth[i]);` I end up getting `[xxxxx], [xxxxx] etc..` where the x's are the values in each "sub-array". What I want to see is the actual name of the array item in the Months array `lcaJan, lcaFeb, lcaMar ...`
I plan on using those as variable in another array. I know, it sounds strange, but it's for a chart.js display:

```
var dataDisplay = [];
    dataDisplay.push ('{data:' + i + ',')
```

I want the dataDisplay to look like this in the end:

> {data: lcaJan}, {data: lcaFeb}, {data: lcaMar}

Comment: Array elements don't have names. What you're trying to get doesn't exist.

Comment: you possibly want key-value pair  in array ,default key is their index

Comment: Youll have to use `{lcaJan: []}` or `[{name: 'jan', data: []}]` to be able to retrieve their names. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not achieve that with arrays, as they do only have numeric index and value

```js
var lcaJan = [], lcaFeb = [], lcaMar = [];
var lcaMonth = [lcaJan, lcaFeb, lcaMar];

lcaMonth.map( (value, index) => console.log(value, index));
```

You can use an Object instead, something like this.

```js
var lcaJan = [], lcaFeb = [], lcaMar = [];
var lcaMonth = {lcaJan, lcaFeb, lcaMar};

for(var key in lcaMonth){ 
  var value = lcaMonth[key];
  console.log(value, key); 
}
```

Comment: Keja - you had the KEY to this solution! Thank you.

Comment: just note that it is ECMAScript 6, so if you need older browser support you might want to use old syntax like `var lcaMonth = {lcaJan: lcaJan, lcaFeb: lcaFeb, lcaMar: lcaMar};` - or use some polyfill